# After successful payment through paypal

Tags: android

After successful payment through paypal  I need to send result to our server api, after successful payment if  the update service is failed due to some reason in this case how I need to handle payment.

Answer (score 0):

there are some callbacks present for the payments success, failure by Paypal in Activity Result, you can check them in Paypal Docs

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Answer (score 0):

If payment is successful and API is not working properly on that time. you have to manage it by yourself on back-end or may hire tech-support team that resolve these problems.